# How to get relation records over relation table issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I developed my first sandbox application, I wanted to get some records for relational table.

User.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #has many followed articles
   has_many :follow_articles
```

And FollowArticle model:

```
class FollowArticle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :article
end
```

And Article model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :follow_articles
end
```

I want to get all followed articles of a user so in my controller I have:

```
@articles = current_user.follow_articles
```

which gave me:

```
ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_FollowArticle:x3014X2
```

In my view I can iterate over these articles:

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
      <%= article.article.name %>
<% end %>
```

which works perfectly.

Can I do this in this way to get an Articles array instead of a FollowArticles array, something like:

```
@items = current_user.follow_articles
```

to return articles instead of followArticles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `has_many :through`.

From [the Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association):

> A has_many :through association is often used to set up a many-to-many connection with another model. This association indicates that the declaring model can be matched with zero or more instances of another model by proceeding through a third model. For example, consider a medical practice where patients make appointments to see physicians. The relevant association declarations could look like this:

```
  class Physician < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :appointments
    has_many :patients, through: :appointments
  end

  class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :physician
    belongs_to :patient
  end

  class Patient < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :appointments
    has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
  end
```

So, fully connecting the dots...

```
  #User.rb 
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :follow_articles
    has_many :followed_articles, through: :follow_articles
  end
```

Comment: ok by what if i had previous used has_many articles to get current user articles ? or it doesnt metter ?

Comment: I modified `has_many :articles` to `has_many :followed_articles`. Where do you currently use `has_many :articles`?

Comment: In the User class?

Comment: yes in User class i have previous declare has_many :articles to get current user articles, but here i want to get followed articles for user. Your's solution is good but you should add after through: :follow_articles , source: :article

Comment: In reference to `source: :article`, the Guide states "You only need to use this option if the name of the source association cannot be automatically inferred from the association name." Anyway, glad I could help. Feel free to accept if you feel so motivated.

Comment: yes and in this case i should use source: :article. Thanks for help and have a nice weekend :)